# Calling UserManager class within oidc-client

Tags: javascript, oidc-client

As a learning exercise, I'm leverage this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@franciscopa91/how-to-implement-oidc-authentication-with-react-context-api-and-react-router-205e13f2d49) to create a React app which uses the "oidc-react" library to manage user identity

Within the article, the author instantiates the "UserManager" class in his own class constructor (see line #8 in screenshot)   But before doing so, appears to "reference" it (see line #5 in screenshot).   Being somewhat new to Javascript, I can't figure out why he's doing that.   I experimentally removed line #5, and doesn't seem to have effect.  Is this some sort of best practice ?   Just trying to learn...

[image]